# CSS drop down menu main tab snag

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have been building a CSS drop down menu and I have a slight snag and wondered if anyone could help me fix this. I have a menu that has this HTML

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">This is sub</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sub menu item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">This is a long sub menu item</a></li>
</ul>
</li>  
<li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
<li><a href="#">another link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Currently when I hover over the main `<li>` 'Home' it's width expands a lot, I think to accommodate the sub-class menus that I have. How can I stop this from occurring? To achieve something like:

|Home| // Nice short main tab
|A sub menu link      |
|Another sub menu link|

As opposed to this that is currently happening (forgive the crudeness of my diagram)

|Home....................| // really long messing up everything tab
|A sub menu link      |
|Another sub menu link|

This is my CSS code for the menu:

```
#menu ul {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
position: relative;
z-index: 40;
}
#menu ul li {
float: left;
padding: 10px 10px 13px 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 50;
}
#menu li a {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
```

Comment: can you whip up a quick JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Jonathon: Here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nupul/N4kFt/ But nothing happens on hovering over 'Home' - what exactly do you want (or are expecting to see?)

Comment: PS: I've added the borders for testing...

Comment: Can't see the difference in your diagrams :) You may want to enclose them in the code blocks - click `{}` on the post editor so that they are properly formatted

Comment: Sorry, i must have omiited soemthing by mistake, here is the JSFiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/gC6Fa/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have basically the same markup so the following code should work well for what you need.

I left all of the color and image info in case you needed help there too.

```
#menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    border: 0 none;
    font: bold 14px "Lucida Sans Unicode","Bitstream Vera Sans","Trebuchet Unicode MS","Lucida Grande",Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    height: 35px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 0 3px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu li a {
    background: no-repeat scroll right bottom #333333;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu li a:hover, #menu ul li:hover a {
    background: no-repeat scroll center bottom #2580A2;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu li ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    border: 0 none;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 225px;
    z-index: 200;
}
#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu li li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 225px;
}
#menu li:hover li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
#menu li ul a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
#menu li ul a:hover, #menu li ul li:hover a {
    background: no-repeat scroll left center #2580A2;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just dropped it in and it does work very well. I thank you and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The markup is weird man.

First of all, try to structure it a little better than having the <a> for the home link in the same <li> as another <ul>.  Can this link be in a separate <li>?

Also, don't wrap the menu in a <div>.  Just apply the styling directly to the parent <ul>.

Comment: Hows the markup weird? It's the principle of the structure not so much that the home tab has a sub menu

Comment: The weird part is having both an <a> and an <ul> within the one <li>, which is not semantic and likely contributing to your issues.  I also don't see the necessity for a wrapping <div>;

Comment: I based that style on the suckerfish mark up which places a UL inside an already open li

Comment: Does it have an <a> as well as a <ul> though inside the one <li>?

Comment: I know its similar, I wanted to try and replicate the LinkedIn menu bar and their source is: <ul class="nav"> 
 <li id="nav-primary-home" class="tab selected"> 
 <a href="/home?trk=hb_tab_home_top"><span>Home</span></a> 
 <ul class="menu"> 
 <li><a href="/home?trk=hb_tab_home">LinkedIn Home</a></li> 
 <li> 
 <a href="/advertising?src=en-all-el-li-hb_tab_ads&amp;utm_medium=el&amp;utm_source=li&amp;utm_campaign=hb_tab_ads&amp;trk=hb_tab_ads">Advertise on Linkedin</a> 
 </li> 
 </ul> 
 </li>